# Refactoring features for ASP.NET Core on VS 2017 are not working very well for me… Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, refactoring

I am in the process of learning ASP.NET Core MVC, while experimenting, I noticed that when I try to refactor the code using the built in refactoring tools provided by Visual Studio they don't work very well. For example:

- Renaming a class via the solution explorer pane usually fails. When it succeeds it will fail to rename the class on the view declaration (eg: @model ClassNameIsNotRenamed);
- If I rename a controller or action, the helper tags such as `asp-controller="NotRenamed"` and `asp-action="NotRenamed"` do not get updated.
- etc.

I don't want to get too detailed on what works and what does not work, the point that I am trying to make is that VS 2017 does not appear to do a good job when it comes to refactoring.

So my question is... Am I asking to much from VS 2017? Is there something that I can do to make refactoring work better?

Thanks.

Comment: There are tools like Resharper that are better at this sort of refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

Doing something like a rename requires that your project can build successfully. If you attempt rename something like a class, and the project either hasn't been built or failed the build, the rename will fail as well. This is fairly logical, as doing a rename refactor requires tracking references, which it can't do without the IL.

As far as your Razor views and controller/action references go, you're dealing with strings and/or code that is not compiled. As a result, it doesn't participate in code-based refactoring generally. Certain things like renames give you option to search strings as well, which you can do to catch more places where things should be renamed, such as your controller/action references. However, that can also cause unwanted side effects if you happen to be using the same string somewhere else, in a different context (which is why string replacement is not done by default).

Comment: I would have thought that helper tags such as "asp-controller" had enough context behind to let the refactoring tools figure out that the string has to be renamed.  I guess I can use trickery such as nameof(MyController.MyAction) to get around the issue..... But what is the deal with the View "@model ClassNameIsNotRenamed"? Is that not compiled? Its weird that you get the squiggly line telling you there is a problem but the compiler does not complain nor does it renames the class even when the project compiles just fine..

Comment: Except those are not actually strong-typed. They're treated as just strings, as they aren't evaluated until runtime.